# how to use flutter code in Apple watch without code full native code?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-watch, channel

Is it possible to run the same flutter code that run in IOS mobile in watch ?

i tried to add the watch target and create a layout to the watch but in native code directly using swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. I'd think that Apple Watch were "locked" with the standard Apple UI for a reason to save battery live and other resources. Flutter, on another hand, implements its own UI rendering just like a "canvas" in javascript world. I don't think that in the nearest future Apple lets developers to render whatever they want using low-level graphics API.

Comment: so basically i should code in native swift like i was doing btw, i just ask because i searched a lot and i didn't find an answer, so i ask the question just to be sure that there is no way, thanks a lot mate